# How to move images using grid?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I'm using this code to display images + text to the screen:

```
root = Tk()
for i in range(5):
    img = some_function_that_returns_ImageTk_PhotoImage()
    ls.append(img)
    panel = Label(root, image = img)
    txt = Label(root, text = str(1+i))
    panel.grid(row = 1, column = i)
    txt.grid(row = 1, column = i)
root.mainloop()
```

and I get these 5 images + text lines displayed, but what I want is to have some space between each image.

- So, I tried changing the `column` value to `2*i` but that didn't
  help. If I changed only the `column` value in `panel`, it lined up
  one image and then one text and so on, until `5 < 2*i` and then it
  went back to lining the images one after the other - not what I
  expected
- Then, I tried changing the `column` value to `2*i` for both `label & txt`. Didn't work either. It actually gave the same results as just using `i`. What am I missing here?

Comment: The size of an empty column is 0, that's why you see no difference between `i` and `2*i`. Have you tried to use `padx` option in `grid`?

Comment: have you read the documentation? There are many options to grid, such as `padx` and `pady`

Comment: I've seen these parameters, but will they "fill" that area? I mean to insert another image between afterwards, would it be OK using padx?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you will need to use padding when setting the grid:

```
panel.grid(row = 1, column = i,padding=(5,5,5,5))
```

you use it as a tuple containing the amount of pixel padding you want for your widget in each direction, i usually set them the same as above, but you can play around and see what works